# UnsupportedClassVersionError using Hudson 3.3.0 with Maven3 and Java 1.6 project

Tags: java, maven, hudson

I'm using hudson 3.3.0 together with a java 7 jre to run hudson itself since the support for a java 6 runtime environment has been dropped with hudson 3.3.0. (see: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=459703 )

Besides that I configured a java 6 jdk and I'm trying to run a job (maven 3.2.5) with this jdk.
The job fails after a few seconds with a 'UnsupportedClassVersionError' because the EventSpy classes are compiled with source level 1.7 and are not working with a java 6 jdk:

> [workspace] $ /home/his/apps/bm/**apache-maven-3.2.5**/bin/mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -V -B -e -Dmaven.ext.class.path=/home/his/data/bm/hudson-3.3.0/maven/slavebundle/resources:/home/his/data/bm/hudson-3.3.0/maven/slavebundle/lib/**maven3-eventspy-3.1**.jar:/home/his/apps/bm/hudson-3.3.0/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/hudson/WEB-INF/lib/hudson-remoting-3.0.3.jar -Dhudson.eventspy.port=53396 -f pom.xml
>   [DEBUG] Waiting for connection on port: 53396
>   Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T18:29:23+01:00)
>   Maven home: /home/his/apps/bm/apache-maven-3.2.5
>   **Java version: 1.6.0**, vendor: IBM Corporation
>   Java home: /home/his/apps/bm/ibm-java-i386-60/jre
>   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
>   OS name: "linux", version: "3.0.76-0.11-default", arch: "x86", family: "unix"
>   [WARNING] Error injecting: org.hudsonci.maven.eventspy_31.DelegatingEventSpy
>   java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.hudsonci.maven.eventspy_31.DelegatingEventSpy not present
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:115)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load(NamedClass.java:46)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:113)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:129)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:46)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1066)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
>       at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1066)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.EntryListAdapter$ValueIterator.next(EntryListAdapter.java:111)
>       at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:370)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.(ArrayList.java:87)
>       at org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyDispatcher.setEventSpies(EventSpyDispatcher.java:49)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanPropertySetter.set(BeanPropertySetter.java:76)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:48)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:52)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:140)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:117)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:92)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:113)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:122)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:269)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1066)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
>       at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1059)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:249)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:419)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:210)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: **JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/hudsonci/maven/eventspy_31/DelegatingEventSpy, offset=6**
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:275)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:529)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:440)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$300(URLClassLoader.java:68)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1027)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:418)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:254)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:107)
>       ... 65 more
>   [ERROR] Error executing Maven.
>   org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

Unfortunately using a Java 7 jdk to run the job is not an option at the moment. Is there a way to get it working with the java 6 jdk?

Comment: Freestyle Projects instead of Maven Project type.

Comment: Just to be sure: You mean I should create a freestyle project and start the maven build via shell script instead of chosing a Maven3-Build step?